# How to get a reference to another component

Tags: angular

I have `componentA` which shows "hello world". I want to open it in `componentB` via a function using the id of `componentA`.

Let's see the code:

ComponentB.html:

```
<app-A  id="content"></app-A>

<button (click)="open(content)">Open A</button> <!-- Error: Property 'content' does not exist  -->
```

ComponentB.ts:

```
open(content: TemplateRef<any>) {
        //call a service 
}
```

The error I get is:
`Property 'content' does not exist on type componentB`

I don't want to use normal parent-child solutions to open `componentA`, I need to open it via the function, is it possible?

Comment: the error is because there is no content variable defined.... but what do you mean by "open it in component B"?  It's already there if "app-A" is componentA's selector.  Are you trying to make a modal?

Answer (score 2):

We have implemented this solution using Hide and Show , using ngIf.

ComponentA.html:

```
<componentA>
<button (click)="ShowComponentB()">View</button>
</componentA>
<componentB *ngIf="isComponentBVisible></componentB>
```

ComponentA.ts:

```
ShowComponentB(){
this.isComponentBVisible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "reach" a component, you use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) (**not** the "id")

```
<!--see the template reference variable #componentA-->
<app-A #componentA id="content"></app-A>

<!--see how you execute a function of the componentA-->
<button (click)="componentA.ShowComponentB()">Open A</button>

<!--or how you pass the componentA to a function in componentB-->
<button (click)="open(componentA)">Open A</button>

//in .ts
open(componentA:any){ //you can use also open(componentA:ComponentA){..}
  ...
}
```